# issue in disabling the textbox in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have bellow code :

```
Private Sub s1_AfterUpdate()
If s1 > 20 Then
MsgBox "Maximum is only 20"
Me.s1= 0
ElseIf s1 = 20 Then
Me.s1_8x12qtty.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

the issue i'm facing is that when I put value to 20 it will disable the **Me.s1_8x12qtty** which i'm good with that as that is what I told it to do... but when I create new record in the form it remain disable for the lifetime of the form... means if I don't close the form it will remain disable even if I create new record and the value of **s1** is zero.

why this happens i'm confused?

regards

Answer (score 1):

> if I don't close the form it will remain disable even if I create new record

It sounds to me like you need a line of code in the `On Current` event of the form to check the value of `s1` and possibly re-enable the control.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another sub to run when creating a new record, or placing this code into the pre-existing sub you may have for the same event:

```
Me.s1_8x12qtty.Enabled = True
```

Comment: How to do that? I could not find any event in new record

Answer (score 0):

Why is this happening?  Once you put a value in the textbox that causes it to become disabled, you can no longer update the value.  Period.  You've put this code in the After_Update event, and that event will never fire again no matter what you do, **unless** you can somehow reset that control another way.

As Gord stated above, checking the value in the On_Current event (or simply resetting the Enabled property to True in the On_Current event) will allow you to reset the control's status every time you move to a new record.

Comment: Hi thanks for the time... how can I add this? on current event? I could not find any event that trigger when creating new record?